# Listening on HttpClientResponse always throws

Tags: dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  client.getUrl(Uri.parse('http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/HttpClientResponse.html'))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
    .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
      response.listen(print, onError: (e) {
        print('error: $e');
      }); 
    });
}
```

The code above doesn't work, using similar method to listen like `pipe` and `fold` also throws an exception => `Breaking on exception: The null object does not have a method 'cancel'.`

**Update**

Here's the code example for when connect to local machine.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 8080)
    .then((HttpServer server) {
      server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
        File f = new File('upload.html');
        f.openRead().pipe(request.response);
      });

      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      client.getUrl(Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8080'))
        .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
          .then((HttpClientResponse response) {
            response.listen(print, onError: (e) {
              print('error: $e');
            });
          });
    });
}
```

It prints out the bytes first and then throw an exception `Breaking on exception: The null object does not have a method 'cancel'.`

Dart Editor version 0.7.2_r27268. Dart SDK version 0.7.2.1_r27268. On Windows 64bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your example works on my machine.

Please specify your Dart version and other system properties that could help debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code presented looks fine, and I have not been able to reproduce the error on either 0.7.2.1 nor bleeding edge. Do you know whether you network has any kind of proxy setup which could cause a direct HTTP connection to fail? You could try connecting to a server on your local machine instead. If it still fails I suggest opening a bug on https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/list with detailed information.

Comment: Yes it still fails even when connecting to local machine, maybe I should file a bug. FYI I updated the post with the code to connect to local machine.